# Share the app using navigation in Android

Tags: android, menu, navigation, fragment

[image]

I am trying to share the app from the menu bar but the navigation part show layout behind the share intent.

I really want same as mainActivity where user clicks on the menu (share the app) and `shareIt();` function call with using navigation.

This is my navigation part:

this is fragment.

```
public class ShareAppFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ShareAppFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ShareAppFragment fragment = new ShareAppFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        share_it();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_share_app, container, false);
        share_it();
        return v;
    }

    private void share_it() {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = Constant.SHARE_IT_MSG;
//        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, CONSTANT.SHARE_IT_MSG);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
}


<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_share_app"
        android:name="a3.bolto.bolto.ui.main.view.nav.ShareAppFragment"
        android:label="@string/share_the_app"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_share_app" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_privacy_policy"
            app:destination="@id/share_appFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_open_enter"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fragment_close_exit" />
    </fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you are using navigation then implement
> "NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener" and
> in ONcreate: do this :

```html
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

> Override it, like this and

```html
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected ( @NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId() ;
        if (id == R.id.nav_share_app ) {
            share_app();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout ) {
            finish();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id. drawer_layout ) ;
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat. START ) ;
        return true;
    }
```